# Polar to Cartesian coordinates conversion in Keplerian orbit

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, polar-coordinates

Suppose you have an elliptical orbit [like this one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcCAB.png). What I have are 2D polar coordinates for any point on it, and the inclination of the ellipse's plane with regard to the reference plane. What I want to do is to obtain the Cartesian coordinates of any such point.

So, what I have given is:

d - distance from the primary,
a - azimuth on the ellipse's plane (true anomaly),
i - inclination of the ellipse's plane to the reference plane.

From this, I want to get the x, y, z coordinates. According to various sources, the formulas are:

x = d*sin(theta)*cos(phi)

y = d*sin(theta)*sin(phi)

z = d*cos(theta)

Of these, I seem only to have the d. How do I divine theta and phi from the available data?

Comment: I’d suggest first converting from 2-D polar to 2-D cartesian in the plane of the orbit, and then mapping that into 3-D.

Comment: Call $x_0=d \cos a$ and $y_0=d \sin a$ the coordinates on the ellipse plane, I think you can assume $x=x_0 \cos i$, $y=y_0$ and $z=x_0 \sin i$.